# react all list items get re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have my state structured like this. It's an object with multiple fields inside of it. For certain purposes, I cannot modify the structure of the state. Here's my component which renders the entire List

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import FoodListItem from '../Food-List-Item'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
`

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.45s ease-in-out, border 0.45s ease-in-out;

  :hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
`

class FoodList extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {
      e5d9d9f5: {
        label: 'ice cream',
        isDelicious: true,
        isHealthy: false,
      },
      a9ba692b: {
        label: 'pizza',
        isDelicious: true,
        isHealthy: false,
      },
      ze128a47: {
        label: 'spinach',
        isDelicious: false,
        isHealthy: true,
      },
    },
  }

  renderListItems = () => {
    const { data } = this.state
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
      return <FoodListItem 
        key={key} 
        {...data[key]}
        id={key}
        handleDecliousChange={this.handleDecliousChange}
        handleHealthyChange={this.handleHealthyChange} 
      />
    })
  }

  handleDecliousChange = (id) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      data: {
        ...state.data,
        [id]: {
          ...state.data[id],
          isDelicious: !state.data[id].isDelicious
        }
      }
    }))
  }

  handleHealthyChange = (id) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      data: {
        ...state.data,
        [id]: {
          ...state.data[id],
          isHealthy: !state.data[id].isHealthy
        }
      }
    }))
  }

  handleShowAppState = () => {
    console.log(this.state.data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {this.renderListItems()}
        <Button type="button" onClick={this.handleShowAppState}>Show App State</Button>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}

export default FoodList;
```

Here's the component which renders a single list item

```
    import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Title = styled.p`
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
`

const Item = styled.div`
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 0em;
  padding-left: ${props => props.isDelicious ? '30px': '0px'}
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: ${props => props.isHealthy ? 'green' : 'gray'};
  transition: background-color 0.45s ease-in-out, padding-left 0.45s ease-in-out;
  color: #ffffff;
`

class FoodListItem extends React.PureComponent {
  deliciousFn = () => {
    this.props.handleDecliousChange(this.props.id)
  }

  healthyFn = (id) => {
    this.props.handleHealthyChange(this.props.id)
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render called', this.props.label);
    const {
      id,
      label, isDelicious, isHealthy,
      handleDecliousChange, handleHealthyChange
    } = this.props
    return (
      <Item isHealthy={isHealthy} isDelicious={isDelicious}>
        <Title>{label}</Title>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={isDelicious} onChange={this.deliciousFn} />
          <label><code>isDelicious</code></label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={isHealthy} onChange={this.healthyFn} />
          <label><code>isHealthy</code></label>
        </div>
      </Item>
    )
  }
}

export default FoodListItem
```

Whenever I click on a single list item, it re-renders all of them. Is there a way to avoid this? Ideally, only the row which was clicked on should re-render.

Comment: `class FoodListItem extends React.PureComponent`

Comment: What @YuryTarabanko asked is correct. A little thing is that pass `data[key]` as spread, instead of the object like [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r652nz66p).  The reason is `{a: 1, b: 2} === {a: 1, b: 2}` always false. `PureComponent` does shallow comparing. If you pass it as an object as you have now, you need to write your own `shouldComponentUpdate` logic to handle the comparisons.

Comment: Is there a better way to write such an app?

Comment: @TarangHirani Your implementation is correct. Nothing wrong, to fix performance you need to do what I said above.

Comment: Thanks Arup. Could you add me on hangouts? I am a little confused about the performance aspect. My hangout email is tarang9211@gmail.com

Comment: @ArupRakshit is there no way to better handle the rendering of the list items?

Comment: @TarangHirani Why do you think your approach is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186456/discussion-between-tarang-hirani-and-arup-rakshit).

Comment: Can we move this to the SO chat @ArupRakshit?

Comment: @ArupRakshit The reason I think the approach is wrong is because in the React DevTools when I select the last FoodListItem and toggle a checkbox, all of them get re-rendered.

Comment: @TarangHirani Did you check my codesandbox code? It doesn't re render all on click on the checkboxex

Comment: @ArupRakshit I have updated the code above. Does it look better? Also using callbacks instead of creating anon functions in the render. That's a better approach. Please do advise.

Comment: I already told you what I know about this. I can't help you any more on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to handle component’s output in `FoodListItem`:

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output
>   is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default
>   behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast
>   majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

```
class FoodListItem extends React.Component {
  //...
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
     return (
       this.props.isDelicious !== nextProps.isDelicious ||
       this.props.isHealthy !== nextProps.isHealthy
     )
  }
  //...
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Or consider using the `PureComponent`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: I used a PureComponent, is there anything else that can be done to improve performance?

Comment: In your case I think you just have to make sure they are not being triggered to re-render. If your app is going to be complicated, consider using `redux` to manage state.

Comment: @TarangHirani I am using MyComponent extends React.PureComponent - yet all the items get rendered on prop change. My props are immutable & don't have any children.